# Change variable hover window background while debugging on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, colors, window

I've been changing thousands of different preferences on Eclipse and I still cannot change hover window background while debugging on Eclipse.
Here is a photo of the black background I want to change the color to: http://img208.imageshack.us/img208/7126/blackbackgrounds.png
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

In Fedora 18 using KDE as desktop you have by default a oxygen-gtk for GTK applications.
You can also change the setting of this color under the following file:

/usr/share/themes/oxygen-gtk/gtk-2.0/kdeglobals

[Colors:Tooltip]
BackgroundNormal=

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Windows->Preferences.

Java->Editor->Appearance color options->Source hover background. I have check-box *System default* set and it is working fine for me.

Comment: First, thanks for replying. However, I can't find the option you told me. This is how my preferences window looks like http://postimage.org/image/solobgi59/

Comment: Well, I have recent version of Eclipse, downloaded from here http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/EclipseJava_HowTo.html

Comment: Doesn't make a difference when changing that, even after restart

Answer (score 2):

For Fedora18 KDE, go to System Settings -> Application Appearance -> Color

Select the tab "Colors" and edit the entry "Tooltip Background"

Answer (score 1):

If you're using gnome, change the system wide tooltip background color:

- System > Preferences > Appearance
- Theme > Customize…
- Colors > Tooltips

([source](http://www.tipstank.com/2010/05/23/solve-eclipse-black-pop-up-code-assist-box-in-ubuntu-10-4-lucid/))